# Aggregate objects inside array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like the following:

```
[ 
 {"sku": 123, "val": 10},
 {"sku": 124, "val":12},
 {"sku": 123, "val": 20}

]
```

Is there a quick way in javascript to sum `val` of objects with the same sku property, so the result would be:

```
[ 
 {"sku": 123, "val": 30},
 {"sku": 124, "val":12}
]
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried thus-far helps people get motivated to help you out faster...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group the entries by their SKU and then map the entries to an SKU and the reduced (sum of) values.

```js
const data = [ 
 { "sku": 123, "val": 10 },
 { "sku": 124, "val": 12 },
 { "sku": 123, "val": 20 }
];

const groupBy = (arr, key) => arr.reduce((acc, entry) => ({
  ...acc, [entry[key]]: [ ...(acc[entry[key]] || []), entry ]
}), {}); 

const sum = Object.entries(groupBy(data, 'sku'))
  .map(([key, values]) =>
    ({
      'sku': key,
      'val': values.reduce((acc, { val }) => acc + val, 0)
    }))

console.log(sum);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here is a more dynamic version that allows for multiple reducers with various aggregation techniques.

```js
const groupBy = (arr, key) => arr.reduce((acc, entry) => ({
  ...acc, [entry[key]]: [ ...(acc[entry[key]] || []), entry ]
}), {}); 

const aggregate = (arr, key, reducers) =>
  Object.entries(groupBy(arr, key))
    .map(([k1, values]) => Object.entries(reducers)
      .reduce((obj, [k2, { fn, initial }]) => ({
        ...obj,
        [k2]: values.reduce((acc, item, index, all) =>
          fn(acc, item[k2], index, all), initial || 0)
      }), { [key]: k1 }))

const data = [ 
 { "sku": 123, "val": 10, "val2": 2 },
 { "sku": 124, "val": 12, "val2": 5  },
 { "sku": 123, "val": 20, "val2": 8  }
];

const aggregated = aggregate(data, 'sku', {
  'val'  : { fn: (acc, val) => acc + val, initial: 0 },
  'val2' : { fn: (acc, val) => acc * val, initial: 1 }
});

console.log(aggregated);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [javascript reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const array = [ 
 { "sku": 123, "val": 10 },
 { "sku": 124, "val": 12 },
 { "sku": 123, "val": 20 }
];

const result = [];

array.reduce((res, value) => {
  if (!res[value.sku]) {
    res[value.sku] = { "sku": value.sku, "val": 0 };
    result.push(res[value.sku])
  }
  res[value.sku].val += value.val;
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the sums in an object:

```js
const arr = [ 
    {"sku": 123, "val": 10},
    {"sku": 124, "val":12},
    {"sku": 123, "val": 20}
];

const sums = {};
for (const {sku, val} of arr) {
    if (!(sku in sums)) {
        sums[sku] = 0;
    }
    sums[sku] += val;
}

const result = Object.entries(sums).map(([k, v]) => ({sku: k, val: v}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but if I have several other attributes in the object (like name, id, thumbnail ...etc), how can I return them without having to write every attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` to build an object with keys as `sku` and values to aggregate. 
Get the `Object.values` from the above object.

```js
const group = (arr) => {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach(({sku, val}) => {
    res[sku] ? (res[sku].val += val) : res[sku] = { sku, val };
  });
  return Object.values(res);
};

const arr = [
  { sku: 123, val: 10 },
  { sku: 124, val: 12 },
  { sku: 123, val: 20 },
];

console.log(group(arr));
```